# PHP class vs function

Tags: php

Quando e por que devo usar uma `class` ao invés de uma `function` simples em PHP?

Por exemplo, eu tenho uma função que executa a inserção de um histórico no banco de dados, que é uma função comum a muitas outras.

---

**funções.php**

```
<?php
function insereHistorico($idUsuario, $descricao) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO historico (id, descricao) VALUES ($idUsuario, $descricao)";
}
```

**arquivo.php**

```
<?php
function adicionaUsuario() {
    //Executa todo o processo aqui
    //...

    //Insere no log
    insereHistorico($idUsuario);
}
```

---

Mas também sei que a mesma função poderia ser uma classe, deste modo:

**funções.php**

```
<?php
class FuncaoClass {

    public function insereHistorico($idUsuario, $descricao) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO historico (id, descricao) VALUES ($idUsuario, $descricao)";
    }
}
```

**arquivo.php**

```
<?php
function adicionaUsuario() {
    //Executa todo o processo aqui
    //...

    //Insere no log
    $funcao = new FuncaoClass;
    $funcao->insereHistorico($idUsuario, $descricao);
}
```

---

O que me parece ser vantagem no uso de classe é ter um código mais organizado, mas como não sou usuário avançado em PHP, não sei quais as principais diferenças ou considerados a respeito desse comparativo.

Apenas para dar o contexto, eu uso PHP para gerenciar o backend de WebSites/WebApps, onde uso AngularJS para chamar essas funções e gerenciar o banco de dados. Normalmente as funções semelhantes ao exemplo do `arquivo.php` me retornam dados (lista de usuários, notícias, pedidos, etc.) enquanto que as funções como a do exemplo do arquivo `funções.php` servem para fazer algum gerenciamento comum a múltiplas funções.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A principal caracteristica da orientação a objeto é juntar ou arramar, a estrutura de dados (geralmente um tipo definido pelo programador) classe, com comportamentos (métodos). Algumas linguagens forçam isso como por exemplo o java, onde não é possível definir uma método/função sem dono (classe), o php permite misturar classes/objeto com funções o que pode ser uma vantagem em alguns casos.

Vantagens da utilização de **classes**:

- Permite de forma simples agrupar e compartilhar elementos (propriedades) entre métodos.
- Métodos podem guardar o estado do objeto.
- Oferece um escopo intermediário entre variáveis globais e locais, comparado a funções e um código estruturado.

Vantagens da utilização de **funções**:

- A chamada de uma função tem sua execução atomica ou seja a ação é realizada ou não, geralmente não possui/guarda estado, o que é bom para códigos onde se tem acessos concorrentes pois não precisam lidar com sincronizações.

Comment: Mas então usar um ou outro, ou até mesmo o uso de ambos em um mesmo projeto não teria nenhum impacto direto, correto? Seria mais relacionado a uma estrutura de código do que a um "melhor método" entre um ou outro. Lógico, sem levar em consideração os pequenos detalhes, como o que você mencionou, por exemplo `Métodos podem guardar o estado do objeto`.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade isso mesmo questão de estrutura, na hora de optar por um ou outra pode se perguntar: preciso guardar estado? isso trás algum benefício? ter um escopo (de váriavel) intermédiario trás algum benefício? é desejável? Uma situação estranha é quando vc tem um objeto e maioria dos métodos pedem argumentos e retorna algum valor mas não armazena estado (por algum motivo) esse é um bom motivo para resvisar a classe, será que utilizar funções não seria melhor e pq? continuar a classe pq? ... continua.

Comment: Outra e mais fácil de detectar são aquelas classes genéricas (práticamente um repositório de funções) que fazem de tudo ou seja falta coesão, uma classe deve apenas ter uma responsabilide (resolver um tipo de problema) e seus métodos devem fazer sentido no contexto. No php é possível agrupar funções por namespace.

Comment: Compreendi. Hoje, no estado atual da minha aplicação, não tenho nenhum caso que seja necessário guardar estado, todas as funções executam algum processo e retornam um valor. Exemplo, criar um link a partir de um id e uma variável, então poderiam ser todos apenas funções. O que gostei do uso de classe é ter uma visão mais clara de onde aquela função está sendo chamada, pois teria algo assim: `ClientClass::carregaCliente()`, por exemplo.

Comment: @rray existe alguma diferença em relação a segurança (já que funciona como um encapsulamento, me corrija se estiver errado)? E de performance (criar uma classe deve gerar mais gastos de recursos do que apenas criar variáveis/funções)? E o que seria "guardar estado"?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam acredito que não. Deve ter alguma diferença mas deve ser pequena no caso do PHP esse tipo de otimização não tem muitos ganhos. Quando você chama um método pode trabalhar com os atributos da classe/objeto (pegar/manipular seus valores atuais ou já acumulados)  e após isso os atribuidos ainda vão existir e ter valores. Já depois da chamada de uma função todas as suas variáveis locais serão destruidas.