# Usar uma classe PHP sem instanciá-la numa variável é a mesma coisa que chamar uma função?

Tags: php, funções, instanciar-objeto

Declarar a classe desta maneira sem instanciá-la numa variável:

```
new ExampleNameClass( 'arg1', 'arg2' );
```

Seria a mesma coisa que usar uma **função**?

```
ExampleFunction('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Já que não armazenei numa variável, o classe executa o *construct* na hora da chamada e morre em seguida... No meu ver, isso seria o comportamento idêntico de uma função simples no PHP. Estou errado?

Então, a vantagem da **classe** comparada a **função**, é que daria para executar **métodos**.

E na função não daria?

```
( new ExampleNameClass('arg1', 'arg2') )->init();
```

Comment: Não dá para executar métodos em funções pois ela dá suporte para isto, mas você pode retornar uma função dentro de função *(!?)* e seguir a mesma lógica. Recomendo a leitura da pergunta [**PHP class vs function**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161031/99718)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é a mesma coisa, e na verdade, geralmente, não faz muito sentido.

De fato, métodos são funções que trabalham com um objeto específico. Sendo que o construtor é uma função especial que cria esse objeto. Pode eventualmente fazer algo além de inicializar o objeto, mas não costuma ser recomendável mais que isto.

Em PHP eu questiono o uso de classes de forma geral. Mas especialmente se for uma classe que sequer terá estado, ou seja, um objeto mesmo. Se ela não terá vários comportamentos não faz o menor sentido ter uma classe na maioria das situações, em qualquer linguagem (a não ser classe estática, o que apenas é um nome não fortuito).

O fato de não armazenar em variável não quer dizer nada, afinal pode estar usando em algum lugar que não exigiu variável ainda (a não ser que não esteja usado). Mas se você tem uma classe costuma ser interessante construir e encerrar em seguida sem fazer mais nada, é quase certo que essa classe não deveria existir.

O último exemplo parece ser muito pior se for só isso que a classe faz, cria-se um objeto, para chamar um método com ele e morre em seguida. Só está fazendo o código ficar mais lento, ocupar mais memória, ser menos legível porque está fazendo aquilo, já que faz pouco sentido, portanto crie uma função.

Se precisar ter uma instância configurável de algo tão simples use uma função anônima em vez pedir um objeto inteiro para isso.

Se não tem um motivo claro e com vantagem justificável, não use. Eu geral eu peço justificativa para a pessoa usar **classe em PHP** e quase sempre não tem justificativa técnica, só política, quando tem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).